# how to match all-caps words execpt for a specific words in regex

Tags: regular-expression

I have a large number of files that contain all caps words that I want to delete, but also there are a small list of those words I want to keep in the files, how can I do it in regex.

for example:

**file1.txt**:

```
hello_world
HELLO
WORLD
HI
hi
test_string
TEST
TESTING
```

I want to remove all the all caps words in this file except `TEST` and `TESTING`
so the output would be

```
hello_world
hi
test_string
TEST
TESTING
```

Comment: Example input file and expected result will be helpful

Comment: sure, updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`, you could do:

```
perl -C -pe 's/\b(?:(TEST|TESTING)|[\p{Lu}_]+)\b/$1/g' your-file
```

Would remove the sequences of one or more uppercase character or underscores that are delimited by non-word characters (word characters being alnums or underscore), except for `TEST` and `TESTING`.

If it's to remove the lines that are made of one such word, you could do:

```
sed -E '/^(TEST|TESTING)$/b
        /^[[:upper:]_]+$/d' your-file
```

Or

```
perl -C -lne 'print if $_ eq "TEST" ||
                       $_ eq "TESTING" ||
                       ! /^[\p{Lu}_]+$/' your-file
```

Or:

```
awk '$0 == "TEST" || $0 == "TESTING" || ! /^[[:upper:]_]+$/' your-file
```

Or `grep` for lines that are `TEST`, `TESTING`, are empty or contain at least one character other than uppercase letters and underscore:

```
grep -E '(^(TEST|TESTING)?$)|[^[:upper:]_]'
```

Comment: "alnums" == "alphanumeric characters"?

Comment: thanks. the sed part worked for me.